# How to make content auto scroll base on time in android similar to Tabs App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scrollview, autoscroll

I am working on music app that display lyrics, I am able to display lyrics in scrollview and when you scroll it is working smooth. But now I want to auto scroll the content and user should be able to able to select speed of scroll. I have seen many auto scroll solution related to textview in stackoverflow but not with content.
Also I have seen this same feature in [Tabs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ultimateguitar.tabs&hl=en_IN&gl=US) App(Screen shot attached below). They are using auto scroll, Can anyone suggest or give me some resource how can I achive that.
Thanks

[image]